# vim command to search&copy lines in selection

Tags: vim

How can I copy lines that is matches a pattern to another line, within a selected part of the document. I can do it for whole document with `:g/\s*$data/co24` but I couldn't figure out how to apply this function to only a selected part of a document.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply a range to the `g` operator.  For example, you can use `V` to select a section of your document, then type `:`, which will get you:

```
:'<,'>
```

Then you can add your `g` command:

```
:'<,'>g/\s*$data/co24
```

You can also apply the range numerically, like this:

```
:100,150 g/\s*$data/co24
```

(This would apply the `g` operation to lines 100-150).  You can *also* apply a range using the search operator, like this:

```
:/start/,/stop/ g/\s*$data/co24
```

This would apply the `g` operation to lines between a match for `start` and a match for `stop`.

Answer (score 1):

Give this a shot, as '<,'> means "within the visual selection"

```
:'<,'>/\s*$data/co24
```